# AspNetIdentity Integrating Offices like Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity

I am currently leveraging certain aspnetcore Identity features like roles.

This comes with advantages like RoleManager.

How do I expand upon this?  I would like to track a users offices (yes, plural) using Identity.

I.E. An identity supported OfficeManager

Comment: Please Elaborate? "This comes with advantages like RoleManager. How do I expand upon this" that is confusing... Give us a Scenario. An application insight where where you want to apply Identity Framework. You want to track users offices how?

Comment: you can check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) for how to expand identity user data